# Unable to add maven url in build.gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am using latest android studio giraffe and I need to add build script in build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url= "https://jitpack.io" } // <---- Add here
    }
}
```

but I am getting error required URI but found string.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. This will be added in settings.gradle under dependençyResolutionManagement and like as below

```
maven{url = uri("https://jitpack.io")}
```

Comment: Ah, ok.  Sorry, I gave you the groovy version.

Java/Kotlin:  "url = uri("xxxx") 
Groovy: "url xxx"

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '=':

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } // <---- Add here
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working as I have already check.